# use no join. cake php

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code.

```
var $uses = array('TABLE1','TABLE2','TABLE3');

function test() {

 $this->Table1->updateAll(
        array('Table1.field1' => 'some value'),
        array('Table1.field1 ' => 'some condition')
            );
......
.....
```

problem is that when I try to update only one table...Table1, it joins other tables with it.

```
UPDATE 
    `Table1`  
LEFT JOIN
    `Table2`  
ON 
    (`Table1`.`id` = `Table2`.`uid`) 
LEFT JOIN 
    `Table3`  
ON 
    (`Table1`.`Table3_id` = `Table3`.`id`) 
SET 
    `Table1`.`field1` = 1  
WHERE 
    some condition.......
```

How can I not join the table and run update only on `Table1`?

**Edit:**

I used this but did not work :

```
$this->Table1->unBindModel(array(hasMany => array('Table2', 'Table3')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly, stop using $uses. it will only cause you more pain than needed.

to avoid the joins use `Model::unbindModel(array('relationType' => array('Relation'))` http://book.cakephp.org/view/1045/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly

Comment: It may be accurate - but stating that something is "broken" or "doesn't work" with no details doesn't help you, and it doesn't help anyone else understand your problem. Give details, what broke, which file, what were you doing at the time, what were you expecting to happen, what did happen, did you see an error message. Whenever possible show the relevant code you are working with. However be as concise - nobody wants to read war and peace if with a few key details you can convey your problem http://book.cakephp.org/view/770/How-to-ask-a-question#Broken-771

Comment: it's `unbindModel()` not `unBindModel`

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your `recursive` level to -1. I'm not sure whether this affects Update calls but it's worth a try.

```
$this->Table1->recursive = -1;
$this->Table1->updateAll(...);
```